# how to update a value of a form upon dropping image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wanna build a drag&drop web app that is updating a form value upon image drop.

Lets say that I have a table in my MySQL database that has pro_name, image, price. Here's my code:

```
<div id = "products">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Object</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $get_prod = "select * from objecttbl where type = 'product'";
    $run_prod = mysqli_query($con,$get_prod);
    while($row_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_prod)){
      $objID = $row_pro['objID'];
      $name = $row_pro['name'];
      $price = $row_pro['price'];
      $image = $row_pro['photo'];
      echo "<tr><td><div class = 'draggable'><img src = 'objects/$image'></div></td>
        <td><h4>$name</h4></td><td>$price</td></tr>";

    }
    ?>
  </table>
</div>

<div id = "dropzone"></div>
<form>
  <input type ="text" name = "price" placeholder = "price" value = "0"/>
</form>
```

I've contained the images inside a draggable `div`. What i want to happen is when I drag an image to the `dropzone`, its price will be added on the form.

Comment: You need to show code for what you have tried already.  SO is not a code writing service and we will not do it for you.

Comment: Ohhh. sorry for that. I've edited my post. Thanks

Comment: @JqueryNewbie where is your JS/jQuery code in this this example?

Comment: My only Jquery code is for the draggable and droppable. I want to know the code for the form value update upon drop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not include a very full example, I have had to take some liberties and you may have to adapt them to your own code.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/njt3x3su/

**HTML**

```
<div id="products">
  <table width="240px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Object</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='draggable'><img src="https://placehold.it/100/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Item+1"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Item 1</h4>
        </td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='draggable'><img src="https://placehold.it/100/00FF00/FFFFFF?text=Item+2"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Item 2</h4></td>
        <td>$2.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='draggable'>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/100/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Item+3">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Item 3</h4></td>
        <td>$3.50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="dropzone" class="addItem"></div>
<form>
  <label for="price">Price: </label>
  <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="price" value="$0.00" />
  <label for="qnty">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="qnty" id="qnty" value="0">
</form>
```

The above HTML may represent the output from your PHP. Since you did not include example output, this is what I created.

**CSS**

```
#dropzone {
  border: 2px dotted #202020;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.addItem {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/200/CFCFCF/000000?text=Add+Item");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -50px -50px;
}
```

Your example did not include any styling, so I do not know if the user would be able to know where to drag items to. I added some. I added a bit in an attempt to create some visual feedback, but I gave up since it's not really in the scope of this question.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var customerItems = [];
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    opacity: 0.75,
    revert: true,
    helper: function() {
      var me = $(this);
      var par = me.parent();
      var item = $("<div>", {
          src: $(this).attr("src"),
          class: "dragItem"
        })
        .css({
          width: "100px",
          height: "100px",
          background: "url('" + me.find("img").attr("src") + "') no-repeat"
        })
        .data({
          name: $.trim(par.next().text()),
          price: parseFloat($.trim(par.next().next().text()).substring(1))
        });
      return item;
    }
  });
  $("#dropzone").droppable({
    //accept: ".dragItem",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "acceptItem",
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(ui.helper.data());
      customerItems.push(ui.helper.data());
      var sum = 0,
        qnty = customerItems.length;
      $.each(customerItems, function(key, item) {
        sum += item.price;
      });
      $("#price").val("$" + sum);
      $("#qnty").val(qnty);
    }
  });
});
```

You had not included any example code, so I do not know what you tried. Basically, your drop will capture details from the dragged item. Once it has those detains, you can add them to the input field using `.val()` method.

So working backward, populate the value of the field with `$("#price").val("$" + sum);` when an item is dropped on the `#dropzone`.

So how do we get the price? It's easiest to get them from the `ui.draggable` or `ui.helper` object. There are lots of ways to store object details with the draggable item. I suggest using the `data` attribute.

Since your HTML does not specifically contain details in the `data` attributes already, but in a table, these details had to be collected when the draggable is selected and moved. A potentially better way to present the data would be like:

```
<div class='draggable' data-name="Item 1" data-price="1.00">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Item+1">
</div>
```

Since it's not clear if you want the user to grab 1 or more, or only one of each, I decided to make a `helper` object to represent the selection. Using a function, we can create a helper object that fits our needs and will contain all the data needed later. From the source we can collect the image, the name, and the price from the various table cells.

Hope that helps. Edit your post and add more details. Comment if you have a question.

Comment: Hi sir Twisty. I appreciate your answer . But what if my data(s)  are from my database? the image, the name, and the price? Is it possible?

Comment: @JqueryNewbie yes it is possible.

Comment: With the same code? I mean i don't have to use SQL queries?

Comment: @JqueryNewbie You will be using a combination of PHP, HTML, and JavaScript/jQuery. jQuery cannot work with SQL directly, that is the job of PHP. As I said in the post, you'll have to adapt this **example** to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answers sir. You're a great help in my study. I salute you.